# How can I set the default directory for adding files to resource in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a resource (resx) file in Visual Studio 2010. When I click `Add Resource > Add Existing File`, I get the `"Add existing file to resources"` dialog window, which defaults to `C:\Windows\System32`

[image]

I want to change this default directory, just like I can change the default directory for Projects by using Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Update: It isn't `C:\Windows\System32`, it is `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`, which was quite confusing when I tried [Equalsk's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760164/set-default-directory-for-adding-files-to-resource-in-visual-studio-2010#comment55287963_33760164).

Comment: I would love to know if this is possible because last time I looked I couldn't find it. I think I ended up putting a shortcut called `__MyFolder` in System32 so at least it was at the top and I could click it every time.

Comment: i think if you choose one file first time the default path changes to path of your previously chosen file.

Comment: No, the default path does not change.